# Trying to fill area in Radar chart using mpandroidchart Java

Tags: java, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to fill in the area of my radar chart made by my dataset. I've used:

```
dataset1.setFillColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 255);
```

I have also tried using:

```
dataset1.setFillColor(Color.RED);
```

Once I run the code nothing happens. Is this the right function or am I not applying it right? This is the only code I have that applies to this problem. I can post all my code for the radar chart if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all you have to do is after setting your color you have to enable .setDrawFilled.

```
dataSet1.setFillColor(Color.rgb(0,0,255));
dataSet1.setDrawFilled(true);
```